# OpenMP recursion slower than without threads

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize the recursion in Karatsuba's polynomial multiply. But it's slower than without threading. What's problem 
I have this code:

```
int karatsubaMain(int size)
{
    Polynom pol1(size),pol2(size);
    omp_set_num_threads(8);
    double start = omp_get_wtime();
    int* result = mult(pol1.polynom,pol2.polynom,0,pol1.size);
    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("%f ", end - start);
    return 0;
}

int * mult(int*a, int *b,int start, int N){
    int * c= new int[2*N-1];
    if(N==1){
        c[0]=a[start]*b[start];
        return c;
    }
    int * t1= new int[N/2];
    int * t2= new int[N/2];
    int * cM,*cL,*cH;
    for(int i=0;i<N/2;i++){
        t1[i]=a[start +i]+a[start + i + N/2];
        t2[i]=b[start +i]+b[start + i + N/2 ];
    }
    #pragma omp parallel shared(cM,cL,cH)
    {
    #pragma omp single nowait
    {
    #pragma omp task if(N > 4096)
    cM=mult(t1,t2,0,N/2);
    #pragma omp task if(N > 4096)
    cL=mult(a,b,0,N/2);
    #pragma omp task if(N > 4096)
    cH=mult(a,b,N/2,N/2);
    }
    #pragma omp taskwait
    }
    c[N-1]=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++){
        c[i]=cL[i];
        c[N+i]=cH[i];
        c[N/2+i]+=(cM[i]-(cL[i]+cH[i]));
    }
    delete []t1;
    delete []t2;
    delete []cM;
    delete []cL;
    delete []cH;
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I show you what you do that you understand the changes better:

In each step you do this:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel shared(cM,cL,cH) //open a new parallel region (ie create threads)
{
  #pragma omp single nowait //only one thread should do the following
  {
    #pragma omp task if(N > 4096) //create task
    cM=mult(t1,t2,0,N/2);
    #pragma omp task if(N > 4096) //create task
    cL=mult(a,b,0,N/2);
    #pragma omp task if(N > 4096) //create task
    cH=mult(a,b,N/2,N/2);
  } //after this line all threads are working on the same
  #pragma omp taskwait   //before executing further the tasks should be finished
} // close all threads created at this parallel
```

what you inteded to do:

create some threads, once create the root of the recursion, every recursive call is a task, all should work on tasks, when all child-tasks are finished calculate result, take new task

in `karatsubaMain()` you should once create threads and one thread then inserts the root task:

```cpp
double start = omp_get_wtime();
int* result; 

#pragma omp parallel shared(result, a, b, size)
{
  #pragma omp single //also #pragma omp master usable here
  result = mult(a, b, 0, size);
}
double end = omp_get_wtime();
```

in `mult()` you shoudl only create tasks since this region is already processed by different threads in parallel:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
{
  t1[i] = a[start + i] + a[start + i + N / 2];
  t2[i] = b[start + i] + b[start + i + N / 2 ];
}
#pragma omp task shared(cM)  if(N > 4096)
cM = mult(t1, t2, 0, N / 2);
#pragma omp task shared(cL)  if(N > 4096)
cL = mult(a, b, 0, N / 2);
#pragma omp task shared(cH)  if(N > 4096)
cH = mult(a, b, N / 2, N / 2);
#pragma omp taskwait

c[N - 1] = 0;
```

in that way i was able to speed up a simplified version of your code (int-array insead of polynom) by about 15% with respect to sequential code.

general remark: most off the times it is not advisable to use nested parallel regions

Comment: On 12 cores cluster is cca 50% speed up. Thank you